# Modular arithmetic Basic cofusion

Tags: discrete-mathematics, number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I am just learning number theory .When I was reading modular arithmetic I came across this statement :

29 is congruent to 15 (mod 7).

So actually this statement actually shows just

29 is congruent to 15

and we are working under mod 7..mod 7 in brackets is just to show the modulus. It is not 29 is congruent to 15%7.It is 29 is congruent to 15 and we are working under modulus 7.

Comment: (aside: you have a typo or the statement in the book is actually wrong)

Comment: (also, you seem to have forgotten to ask a question)

Comment: Book is MIT Maths for computer science

Comment: Notice that even though (mod 7) appears over on the right side, the 
symbol, it isn’t any more strongly associated with the 15 than with the 29. It would
really be clearer to write 29  <(subscript)mod 7> 15 for example, but the notation with the
modulus at the end is firmly entrenched and we’ll stick to it.

Comment: meaning of this line

Comment: So is it 27 or 29? And, btw, do you have a question? This site is for questions and answers.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about number theory / [math.se] instead of programming or software development.

Answer (score 0):

Your observation is correct. The word mod is actually used in two different senses: one of them is to clarify a relation as you describe

> `A = B  (mod C)`

means, e.g., that `B-A` is divisible by `C`. Or sometimes (but equivalently in the end), it means that you should be reading `A` and `B` as being notation, e.g., for elements of the algebraic structure integers modulo `C` rather than as notation for integers.

The other usage is as a binary operator: `B mod C` means the remainder when `B` is divided by `C`.

Usually it's straightforward to tell the difference from context... assuming you are actually aware of both possible usages. Also, in the first kind of usage, mod is usually set off from the others; e.g.

> `A = B    mod C`

is the first usage as a relation, but

> `A = B mod C`

could go either way.

Comment: So (mod 7)is just to show we are working under modulus 7 and I can just say that 29 is congruent to 15 is congruent to 36 without specifying mod 7 again and again

Comment: If it's clear from context. Sometimes you can't; e.g. in an argument that mixes integer equations with modular equations, or a calculation in which the modulus varies. e.g. if you have the equation `2x = 2y mod 2z`, then dividing by `2` gives you an equation `x = y mod z`.

Comment: Suppose we have 29*x is congruent to 15 (mod 7) and we have to find x (modulo inverse of 28) we write it as x is congruent to 15/29 (mod 7) not     x is congruent to 15/29 (mod 7/29). Therefore I am just conforming (mod 7 ) is written outside just we working under mod 7 and we other arithmetic calculations such as add subtract to both 29*x and 15 by moving 29 under 15  as 15/29 not in mod 7/29